# PHP Post Form, Can't upload files over 25MB

Tags: php, upload

So I've changed all these values in php.ini:

Max file upload size = 10000M

post upload size = 11000M

Excecution Max Time = 12000

Input Max Time = 12000

Im also using a PHP form which uploads multiple files at once:
index.php (file upload form, other code on page which requires php backend)

```
 <input type="hidden" value="form" name="<?php echo ini_get('session.upload_progress.name'); ?>">
    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn">Drag File / Click to upload</button>

      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="fileToUpload">
    </div>

</form>
  document.getElementById("fileToUpload").onchange = function() {
      startUpload();
      setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("form").submit();}, 1000);
}


</script>
```

Again, I can upload normal files fine, but large files dont work.
heres the file upload php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//boi

$max_file_size = 20000000; //2GB
$path = $_SESSION["directory"]."/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
    header("location: index.php");
?>
```

the site this is live on is: http://simpledrive.duckdns.org/simple

thanks.

Comment: you have it to change in your php.ini file. Because theyset there also a limit PS its 25MB there

Comment: Could it be a webserver restriction?

Comment: @xmastertje What value do i need to change in the php.ini exactly.

Comment: @Daan Im running it on apache2, on Raspberry pi 2b+, raspbian lite. (1Gb RAM, 4 core 1ghz debian based u know)   thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: change your .htaccess

Comment: @xmastertje I have done so, http acess i edited is this: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-defult.conf:  code i pasted at bottom of file is this:                                                                                              <IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 106969M
php_value post_max_size 116969M
</IfModule>

Comment: Realised thats not httpacess. So i made a .htacess file in same directory as upload php and uploadForm.php files. and pasted in: php_value upload_max_filesize 10240M
php_value post_max_size 10240M

Answer (score 0):

Time for me to answer my own question, So turns out it was a couple lines of code in the upload script I had written/coppied from all over the place.

```
$max_file_size = 20000000;
if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
```

Turns out the `['files']['size'][$f]` here was massivley larger than `$max_file_size.` 
even set at **20000000**.

Thanks for your help anyway guys.

[to be honest, im kinda retarted (meme image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4xej.png)